# Django Foreign Key indexing in Solr Haystack

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I am trying to index my models which has one to many (foreign key) relationships. And I couldn't handle how to declare search_indexes.py for that, anyone knows what to do for that:

models.py:

```
class CarModel(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

search_indexes.py:

```
class ManufacturerIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    carmodel = MultiValueField(indexed=True, stored=True, faceted=True)

    def prepare_carmodel(self, obj):
        return ???????????????????    

    def get_model(self):
        return Manufacturer
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the `Manufacturer` instance, so you need to reverse the `ForeignKey` relationship to create a list of pks (in this case) to be saved in the `MultiValueField`

```
def prepare_carmodel(self, obj):
    return [int(cm.pk) for cm in obj.carmodel_set.all()]
```

Comment: I tried it, seems like it fails with unknown field 'carmodel'

Comment: You must be missing `carmodel = MultiValueField(indexed=True, stored=True, faceted=True)`... You need both the field declaration AND the `prepare_` method.